# Converting Dataframe into a specific dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe (datfrm) consisting 15000 rows and 50 columns as follows:

```
    datfrm:

    Id,         date,      f1,  f2,   …,    f48
    01,   01-01-2017,      23,  12,   …,         32
    01,   01-02-2017,      03,  22,   …,         21
    01,   01-03-2017,      44,  12,   …,         36
            ---
    01,   01-12-2017,      62,   8,   …,         43
    02,   01-01-2017,      21,  11,   …,         23
            ….
    0n,   01-12-2017,      33,  23,  ….,         29
```

I want to convert this dataframe into a dictionary with 12 keys, where each key (m1, m2,…,m12) contains the data which have ‘date’ in that specific month, e.g., Jan or Feb. In other words, I want to group them based on the “date” in 12 keys in a dictionary. I also need to preserve the index of the rows when they are converted to the dictionary. So my desired dictionay shpuld be like this:

```
 m_dict.keys():

          dict_keys(['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6',       
                 'm7','month8', 'm9', 'm10', 'm11', 'm12']) 

     m_dict[‘m1’]:
            Id,      date,          f1,     f2,  …,         f48
            01,      01-01-2017,    23,     12,      …,      32
            02,      01-01-2017,    21,     11,      …,      23
            03,      01-01-2017,    17,      3,      …,      32
```

Comment: Groupby is what you need here. Simply the way to extract the month depend on the type of the data column. Long story short: is it a string or a true date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# convert to date if needed
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, dayfirst=True)

m_dict = {f'm{v}':g for v,g in df.groupby(df.date.dt.month)}
```